# Search values only from first element in linq c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the problem in where condition please check this

```
<Uni_Details Uni_ID="U001" User_Mode="New">
  <Uni_Name>
    <Full_Name>Asian</Full_Name>
    <Short_Name />
  </Uni_Name>
  <Asc_Uni>
    <Asc_Details Asc_Name="Stafford">
      <Asc_Add>fsfadfsdfsdfsdf</Asc_Add>
      <Asc_Tel>+44 34234234234</Asc_Tel>
      <Asc_Country>United Kingdom</Asc_Country>
      <Asc_Web>www.ac.lk</Asc_Web>
    </Asc_Details>
  </Asc_Uni>
  <Branch>
    <Branch_Details Branch_Name="Head Office">
      <Branch_Add>dasdasdadsd</Branch_Add>
      <Branch_City>Colombo</Branch_City>
      <Branch_Country>Sri Lanka</Branch_Country>
      <Branch_Tel>+94 342432423</Branch_Tel>
    </Branch_Details>
    <Branch_Details Branch_Name="Access Tower">
      <Branch_Add>dfgdfgdfgdf</Branch_Add>
      <Branch_City>Colombo</Branch_City>
      <Branch_Country>Sri Lanka</Branch_Country>
      <Branch_Tel>+94 342432453</Branch_Tel>
    </Branch_Details>
  </Branch>
  <Uni_EMail>info@apiit.lk</Uni_EMail>
  <Uni_Web>www.apiit.lk</Uni_Web>
  <Course_Data>
    <Course_Details Course_ID="U001C001">
      <Course_Name>Computer Course</Course_Name>
      <Course_Qual>Pass O/L</Course_Qual>
      <Course_Dur>3 Months</Course_Dur>
      <Course_Content>
        <Course_Conent_List>C#.net</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>VB.Net</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>Design Practices</Course_Conent_List>
      </Course_Content>
      <Course_Fee>
        <Fee_Amount Amount_Currency="SL Rs.">5000.00</Fee_Amount>
        <Fee_Comment>Onwards</Fee_Comment>
      </Course_Fee>
      <Course_Desc>Learn Basic Programming practices</Course_Desc>
      <Course_Next>Next October</Course_Next>
      <Category_List>
        <Cat_ID>2</Cat_ID>
        <Cat_ID>1</Cat_ID>
      </Category_List>
    </Course_Details>
  </Course_Data>
</Uni_Details>
<Uni_Details Uni_ID="U002" User_Mode="New">
  <Uni_Name>
    <Full_Name>American College</Full_Name>
    <Short_Name>AC</Short_Name>
  </Uni_Name>
  <Asc_Uni>
    <Asc_Details Asc_Name="American College USA">
      <Asc_Add>fasdfsdfsdfsdsdfs</Asc_Add>
      <Asc_Tel>+94 112 230623</Asc_Tel>
      <Asc_Country>United States</Asc_Country>
      <Asc_Web>www.ac.lk</Asc_Web>
    </Asc_Details>
  </Asc_Uni>
  <Branch>
    <Branch_Details Branch_Name="Head Office">
      <Branch_Add>FFSDFASDFSDF</Branch_Add>
      <Branch_City>Colombo</Branch_City>
      <Branch_Country>Sri Lanka</Branch_Country>
      <Branch_Tel>+94 112 230623</Branch_Tel>
    </Branch_Details>
  </Branch>
  <Uni_EMail>info@ac.lk</Uni_EMail>
  <Uni_Web>www.ac.lk</Uni_Web>
  <Course_Data>
    <Course_Details Course_ID="U002C0001">
      <Course_Name>Computer Course</Course_Name>
      <Course_Qual>O/L Pass</Course_Qual>
      <Course_Dur>3 Months</Course_Dur>
      <Course_Content>
        <Course_Conent_List>C#.net</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>VB.Net</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>Design Practices</Course_Conent_List>
      </Course_Content>
      <Course_Fee>
        <Fee_Amount Amount_Currency="SL Rs.">5000</Fee_Amount>
        <Fee_Comment></Fee_Comment>
      </Course_Fee>
      <Course_Desc>Basics</Course_Desc>
      <Course_Next>Next October</Course_Next>
      <Category_List>
        <Cat_ID>1</Cat_ID>
      </Category_List>
    </Course_Details>
    <Course_Details Course_ID="U002C0002">
      <Course_Name>Accounting Course</Course_Name>
      <Course_Qual>O/L Pass</Course_Qual>
      <Course_Dur>6 Months</Course_Dur>
      <Course_Content>
        <Course_Conent_List>Accounts Basics</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>Business Studies</Course_Conent_List>
        <Course_Conent_List>Acc Pack</Course_Conent_List>
      </Course_Content>
      <Course_Fee>
        <Fee_Amount Amount_Currency="SL Rs.">10000</Fee_Amount>
        <Fee_Comment></Fee_Comment>
      </Course_Fee>
      <Course_Desc>Basic Accounting</Course_Desc>
      <Course_Next>Next January</Course_Next>
      <Category_List>
        <Cat_ID>3</Cat_ID>
        <Cat_ID>2</Cat_ID>
      </Category_List>
    </Course_Details>
  </Course_Data>

</Uni_Details>
```

this is my XML file I need to retrieve all data which cat_id is 1

```
 var data = (from cats in data_file.Elements("Uni_Data").Elements("Uni_Details")
                where cats.Element("Course_Data").Element("Course_Details").Element("Category_List").Element("Cat_ID").Value == cat_id.ToString()
                select new
                {
                    uni_name = cats.Element("Uni_Name").Element("Full_Name").Value.ToString(),
                    uni_short = cats.Element("Uni_Name").Element("Short_Name").Value.ToString(),
                    price = cats.Element("Course_Data").Element("Course_Details").Element("Course_Fee").Element("Fee_Amount").Value.ToString()
                });
```

however this works if I have cat_id 1 as my first element if its in second place it won't listed so plz help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way the end of your `where` clause is setup: `Element("Cat_ID").Value == cat_id.ToString()`.

Specifically, the `Element("Cat_ID")` part will check the first child "Cat_ID" element. So if Cat_ID 1 is the second item, it won't be found. Instead, you need to check all child elements for a match.

```
var data = (from cats in data_file.Elements("Uni_Data").Elements("Uni_Details")
            let catId = cats.Element("Course_Data").Element("Course_Details").Element("Category_List").Elements("Cat_ID").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == cat_id.ToString())
            where catId != null
            select new
            {
                uni_name = cats.Element("Uni_Name").Element("Full_Name").Value.ToString(),
                uni_short = cats.Element("Uni_Name").Element("Short_Name").Value.ToString(),
                price = cats.Element("Course_Data").Element("Course_Details").Element("Course_Fee").Element("Fee_Amount").Value.ToString()
            });
```

The query uses a `let` clause to store the result of the `FirstOrDefault` call, which uses the predicate to match the criteria. Next, if it isn't null then the rest of the query works as before. If it's null it means no match was found.

That said, your query has a lot of repeated elements. It also uses `.Value.ToString()` in a few places, which is redundant since the `Value` property already returns a string. I would clean up the query as follows:

```
var data = from cats in data_file.Elements("Uni_Data").Elements("Uni_Details")
           let uniName = cats.Element("Uni_Name")
           let details = cats.Element("Course_Data").Element("Course_Details")
           let catId = details.Element("Category_List").Elements("Cat_ID").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == cat_id.ToString())
           where catId != null
           select new
           {
               uni_name = uniName.Element("Full_Name").Value,
               uni_short = uniName.Element("Short_Name").Value,
               price = details.Element("Course_Fee").Element("Fee_Amount").Value
           };
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Ahmad Mageed it was up to the point. Thank you once again